# How can I disable/mute Terminal printing function for a shell file?

Tags: bash, terminal

I have a shell file that contains this below code, the name of shell is `test.sh`:

```
echo "Hello, world!"
cd ${HOME}
cd Desktop
mkdir "New Folder"
echo "Folder is Successfully created!"
```

And then I am running that code with `bash test.sh`, so far so good! In some point I want the file be mute and do not print any thing to Terminal without modifying the `test.sh` file itself, in other words I want keep the logic of code the same but adding some code out side of it to make Terminal print nothing. how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pipe all output to `/dev/null`

As in `./test.sh > /dev/null 2>&1`

- `>` Means redirect output
- `/dev/null` basically means "to nowhere"
- `2>&1` means send error messages to the same place regular text goes to.  Technically these are called SDTOUT (1) and STDERR (2).

You *should* add what is called a "[Shebang](https://linuxize.com/post/bash-shebang/)" or "[Shebang line](https://linuxize.com/post/bash-shebang/)" to the first line of your script.  This tells your shell how to run the script.
YOUR first line should read something like this: `#!/bin/bash` to tell the system that this file is to be executed with bash (pretty nifty.. right?).

This plus changing the attributes of the script to be executable is simply how it is done properly.  This is done by running the `chmod` command.. as in `chmod +x ./test.sh`.

From that point on, you can run the script directly without invoking bash in the abhorrent manner that you are doing above ;)  Linux people will give you hell if you do this any other way. :)  Please don't shoot the messenger.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I would upvote if I could. I got a side question, all code are good and perfect, If I wanted Terminal print nothing I should use `bash test.sh > /dev/null 2>&1` what about I we would like get error or warning and ignore other outputs?

Comment: Remove the `2>&1` from the end and you will still get errors. :)